# Javascript only works after page reload

Tags: javascript

There is a search field with id #surch and a table with a lot of tr´s and on `keyup` I want to hide all the table tr´s that do not contain the string entered in #surch. I embedded it with `<script src...>` to all files of my website and it works fine on my `index.php`; on all the other subpages it is only working after page reload.

Can anyone give me some help this is driving me crazy. I have tried to add a php function that increments the javascript sourcecode every time (`...sufu.js?updated=266`) but it is not solving my problem.

edit: i have also google adsense running on my page and it is the same problem here. adsense is just running after reload. any ideas ?

```
var $rows = $('#table tr');
$('#surch').keyup(function() {
  var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

  $rows.show().filter(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    return !~text.indexOf(val); 
  }).hide();
});
```

Comment: Have included your code within $(document).ready(function(){/* your code here*/});  ?  For jquery mobile use jQuery(document).on("mobileinit",function() {/*your code here*/}); for specific pages jQuery(document).on('pageinit'.... check out api http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/

Comment: i am also using jquery and jquery mobile on my page

Comment: Sounds like your function is trying to run before the dom or jQuery is ready. On reload the resources are cached and so are available to your function.

Comment: @melc, it´s not working for me.

Comment: @Moob sounds logical, do you know a way to solve this problem?

Comment: @DominikZinser yes, load jQuery in the header and put your functions in a `$(document).ready(function(){/*your code here*/})` like already suggested. ;)

Comment: hm that´s what i am doing

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me in this JSFiddle. [Try it out.](http://jsfiddle.net/yL5Fm/)

```
<input type=text id='surch'>
<table id='table'>
  <tr><td>x</td></tr>
  <tr><td>y</td></tr>
  <tr><td>z</td></tr>
  <tr><td>p</td></tr>
</table>
```

Of course I've assumed that your table has an id 'table', which your $rows selector requires. Otherwise you would simply select $('table tr').

(Edit: also, yeah, I've assumed your JS runs on document load.)